# Enterprise Architect (Sparx Systems) - add parameter name and type in parameter list

Tags: enterprise-architect

I cannot get the name of the parameter to show up in class diagram generated by 'Enterprise Architect'  (Sparx Systems). I am trying to add a operation below

```
+ delayFight(numberOfMinutes: int) : Date
```

but after I add the parameter name and type, the operation is displayed as this

```
+ delayFight(int) : Date
```

Does anyone know how to force it to show the parameter name as well?

Thanks

Answer (score 31):

Figured out how to do it.

From the main menu

```
diagram -> properties -> features -> show parameter detail -> (full)
```